# bessel function maximizer

Tags: analysis, special-functions

I try to find global maximum for $ \frac{J_2(x)}{x^2} $  I suspect it happens at x=0 ( plotting the graph) where the value of the function is $ \frac{1}{8} $ 
I know local maximizers are at   zeros of $ J_3(x) $ since $ \frac{d}{dx}\frac{J_2(x)}{x^2}=-\frac{J_3(x)}{x^2} $. 
My problem is to evaluate $ \frac{J_2(x)}{x^2} $  at the zeros of  $ J_3(x) $ or compare it to 
$ \frac{1}{8} $ .
thanks.

Comment: You should probably use a capital $J$ to write $J_2(x)$ to prevent confusion with the [spherical Bessel functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Spherical_Bessel_functions:_jn.2C_yn).

Answer (score 1):

From Abramowitz/Stegun 9.1.62 or http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.14#E4 we know that
$$|J_\nu(z)|  \le \frac{|\frac{1}{2}z|^{\nu}e^{|\Im z|}}{\Gamma(\nu+1)}$$
for $\nu \ge -\frac{1}{2}\cdot$ Assuming that your $x$ is real this implies

$$|J_2(x)|  \le \frac{|\frac{1}{2}x|^2e^{0}}{\Gamma(2+1)}= \frac{x^2}{8},$$
from which your result follows with division by $x^2$ and the continuity of your function at $x=0$.